# How to use R's assignment methods in rpy2?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm working with rpy2, and I need to use an assignment method on an R object. For example, starting with this object:

```
# Python code
from rpy2.robjects import r
myvar = r('c(a=1,b=2,c=3)')
```

suppose that I want to assign to `names(myvar)`. (Note: Ignore the fact that rpy2 provides an alternate way to access names via `myvar.names`. This only works for names, not arbitrary assignment methods.) In R, I would do:

```
# R code
names(myvar) <- c("x", "y", "z")
```

However, this won't work in Python:

```
# Python code
> names(myvar) = ['x', 'y', 'z']
In [62]: names(myvar) = ['x', 'y', 'z']
  File "<ipython-input-62-aa3f7998cdcb>", line 1
    names(myvar) = ['x', 'y', 'z']
                                  ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Of course, I can run arbitrary code via rpy2's string eval:

```
# Python code
r('''names(myvar) <- c("x", "y", "z")''')
```

but interpolating values into a string to be evaluated doesn't sound fun or safe. So is there a way to safely do the equivalent of `method(object) <- value` through rpy2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In R, "setter" functions follow a naming convention that makes the name of the "getter" followed by `<-`. For example, when doing

```r
names(myvar) <- c("x", "y", "z")
```

the following is happening:

```r
myvar <- "names<-"(myvar, c("x","y","z"))
```

If we break it down:

```r
> myvar = c(a=1,b=2,c=3)
> # call the assignment function "names<-"    
> "names<-"(myvar, c("x","y","z")) 
x y z 
1 2 3 
> # the "names" are stored as an attribute
> attributes(myvar)
$names
[1] "x" "y" "z"
> attributes(myvar)$names <- c("a","b","c")
> myvar
a b c 
1 2 3 
> # note that the function does have a side effect
> # (unlike what I wrote in a previous version of this answer):
> # the names are changed in place. I think that this is a C-level
> # optimization specific to "names" and this may not always be
> # the case for all "setters"
> "names<-"(myvar, c("x","y","z")) 
x y z 
1 2 3 
> myvar
x y z 
1 2 3
```

Doing something like `method(object) <- value` from rpy2 is straightforward. The python code is looking like:

```py
set_method = r("`method<-`")
my_object = set_method(my_object, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider importing R's base package and directly use the `c()` function and to assign names import R's stats package and directly use the `setNames()` function. Below shows how assigning with `r()` and `base.c()` yield equivalent values:

```
from rpy2.robjects import r
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

base = importr('base')

myvar1 = r("c('x','y','z')")
myvar2 = base.c('x', 'y', 'z')

# SAME CLASS TYPE
print(type(myvar1))
# <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.StrVector'>
print(type(myvar2))
# <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.StrVector'>

from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

# CONVERT TO PYTHON NUMPY ARRAY
py_myvar1 = pandas2ri.ri2py(myvar1)
py_myvar2 = pandas2ri.ri2py(myvar2)

print(py_myvar1==py_myvar2)
# [ True  True  True]

print(py_myvar1)
# ['x' 'y' 'z']
print(py_myvar2)
# ['x' 'y' 'z']
```

And for assigning names with output vectors of names and values:

```
stats = importr('stats')
# EQUIVALENT TO R: myvar <- setNames(c('a', 'b', 'c'), c(1,2,3))
myvar3 = stats.setNames(base.c(1,2,3), base.c('a', 'b', 'c'))

print(type(myvar3))
# <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.IntVector'>

# NAME VECTOR
py_myvar3 = pandas2ri.ri2py(base.names(myvar3))
print(py_myvar3)
# ['a' 'b' 'c']

# VALUES VECTOR
py_myvar3 = pandas2ri.ri2py(myvar3)
print(py_myvar3)
# [1 2 3]
```

Altogether, Python does not allow function calls to be assigned values. So find the appropriate method to create an object and assign right hand side values to it aligning to Python's convention.

Comment: This works for names, but not arbitrary setter functions. I wish I could think of a simple example involving a setter other than `names<-`.